# Selecting data from a CSV and entering that data into a table in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to figure out how to iterate through rows in a .CSV files and enter that data into a table in sqlite but only if the data in that row meets certain criteria.

I am trying to build a database of my personal spending. I have used python to categorise my spending data I now want to enter that data into a database with each category as a different table. This means I need to sort the data and enter it into different tables based on the category of spend.

I looked for quite a long time. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not adding all data, then delete rows which does not match criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the CSV file using pandas and store it in a pandas DataFrame. Then (If you did not create already a database) use SQLAlchemy library ([Here is the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/)) to create an engine `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///file.db')`.

Afterwards, you need to convert the DataFrame to the SQL database using pandas to_sql function ([Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html?highlight=to_sql#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql)). `df.to_sql('file_name', engine, index=False)`. I used the `index=False` to avoid creating a column for the index of the DataFrame.